# When is $c^4-72b^2c^2+320b^3c-432b^4$ a positive square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

In trying to solve a certain [third-degree] Diophantine equation, I have used the quadratic equation to determine that
$$c^4-72b^2c^2+320b^3c-432b^4$$
must be a positive integer square, where $c$ and $b$ are positive integers.

From [admittedly limited] maxima calculations, it appears that the complete solution set is $(c,b) = (27k,5k)$ for $k = 1,2,3,\dots$.

I've tried to prove this, but have had no luck so far. Any hints or links/references to useful papers and techniques would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The original equation I was trying to solve is
$$y^2 = x^3 - 2. \tag{$\star$}$$
I am aware of the solution to this equation (see, for example, Conrad's paper, and about a dozen questions on this site), and so am not looking for a direct solution to ($\star$). Rather, I am interested in discovering techniques — especially elementary ones — by which one may attack the [type of] equation in the question.

Comment: For what reason do you withhold the full problem, and only give us this derived problem? People might be able to help with the original question...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The original problem is a Mordell equation, for which there are known solutions. Ultimately, I am trying to find general techniques, rather than particular solutions, so I didn't want to bias the answer(s) I received.

Comment: But, for instance, the answer below took your equation and argues that you can convert it to an elliptic curve, but a Mordell equation is already an elliptic curve. So, by not giving the original equation, you've actually made it harder for people to help you.

Comment: Yes, that's one answer. Hopefully there will be others. In the meantime, I have edited my original question by adding the Mordell equation I am studying.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: I gave a elementary method which you can easily apply to other situations when you need to solve a quartic $F(x) = y^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, an equation,

$$F(x) = y^2$$

with an initial rational point $x$ and where $F(x)$ is a quartic polynomial can be transformed into an *elliptic curve*, hence there should be an infinite number of rational points $x$. It is the case for your particular curve,

$$x^4 - 72 x^2 + 320x - 432 = y^2$$

with,

$$x_1 = c/b = 27/5$$

$$x_2 = c/b = 649193045949/48488608130$$

where $x_2$ is not reducible to $x_1$ and so on, *ad infinitum*.

(P.S. I've probably missed a smaller solution.)

> $\color{blue}{Edit:}$ Here's an elementary method how to find more solutions $x_i$.

(I believe it is called the *tangent method* and goes back to Fermat.) Simply equate,

$$x^4 - 72 x^2 + 320x - 432  =(a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)^2$$

collect powers of $x$ to get,

$$p_4x^4+p_3x^3+p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0 = 0\tag1$$

and for this particular quartic, your three unknowns $a_0,a_1,a_2$ are enough to set $p_4 = p_3 = p_2 = 0$ and making the $x^4, x^3, x^2$ vanish, leaving you with,

$$x = -p_0/p_1 = 27/5$$

To get *more* solutions, do the substitution $x = v+27/5$, to get,

$$v^4+108/5v^3+2574v^2/25+21532/125v+(171/25)^2 = (b_2v^2+b_1v+b_0)^2$$

which you assume to be a square in the RHS. Collect powers of $v$,

$$q_4v^4+q_3v^3+q_2v^2+q_1v+q_0 = 0\tag2$$

Your three unknowns $b_0,b_1,b_2$ are also enough to set the other end $q_0 = q_1 = q_2 = 0$ and making the $v^0, v^1, v^2$ vanish, leaving you with,

$$q_4v^4+q_3v^3 = (q_4v+q_3)v^3  = 0$$

Hence,

$$x_2 = v+x_1 = -q_3/q_4+27/5 = 649193045949/48488608130$$

I'm sure with this easy method, you now have a technique to generate new solutions from old ones.

Comment: Ah yes, there is also $x = c/b = 5383/855$.

Comment: Thanks for the lovely technique. I look forward to investigating it further.

Comment: Can this method be used to find _all_ solutions? e.g., how does one find $c/b=5383/855$ in the first place?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: You solve for the other end of $(2)$, $q_4 = q_3 = q_2 = 0$ hence $$x_3 = v +x_1 = -q_0/q_1+27/5 = 5383/855$$ I'm not sure if it can find _all_ solutions but, for appropriate quartics, it does give an infinite number of them.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701700/seeking-general-methods-to-attack-ax4bx3ycx2y2dxy3ey4-z2-in-integer)