# When is $c^4+4bc^3-4b^4$ an integer square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I’m trying to characterize positive integers $c$ and $b$, with $\gcd(c,b) \mid 2$, such that $c^4+4bc^3-4b^4$ is an integer square.

The solutions I’ve found [by brute force calculation] are
$$(c,b) = (1,1), (2,2), (17,6), (34,12), (113,66), (226,132), …$$

In lieu of a full characterization, I’m also content [for the purposes of the puzzle I’m working on] to show that $c < 3b$ always holds, which appears to be true from the limited data set I have so far.

I’ve tried writing it out as
$$(c^2+2bc)^2 = k^2+(2b^2)^2+(2bc)^2$$
for some integer $k$, and then applying the parameterization of the 2.1.3 Diophantine equation, but nothing useful popped out. Any advice or hints (or complete answers!) would be appreciated.

EDIT: From [an earlier, similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321334/when-is-c4-72b2c2320b3c-432b4-a-positive-square) — which I only now recalled, because MSE linked it automatically in the ‘Related’ section! — I see that Fermat’s tangent method should apply. I’ll work on that, but I’d appreciate it if anyone can provide some hints/shortcuts on how to prove (or, I suppose, disprove?!) that $c<3b$, either for all rational solutions or just for the integer solutions.

Comment: Note that, if $(c,b)$ is a solution, then so is $(nc, nb)$  so you should focus on pairs with $\gcd(c,b)=1$.

Comment: $c \gt 3b: (b,c)=(196692, 1213537),(37974975116778, 247391970393905)$

Comment: @Tomita: Thanks for the counterexamples.

Comment: @Tomita How did you find those solutions ?

Comment: @Peter The equation is reudced to an elliptic curve $Y^2 = X^3+X-1$.
These solutions are derived by group law with generator $(X,Y)=(1,1)$.