# Finding inverse of birational transformation.

Tags: elliptic-curves, rational-functions, sagemath, birational-geometry

I have two algebraic curves over $\Bbb Q$:

$$C:y^2=x^4+4x^3-4$$
and the Elliptic curve

$$E:y^2=x^3 + 16x-64$$

which I computed using Sage, so that I can apply the group law on $E$ to perform arithmetic on rational points.  Sage also provides a birational map $f:C\to E$ so that one can transform points on $C$ to points on $E$:

$$f:\binom xy\mapsto \binom{(4x^4 + 16x^2 + 32x)/y^2}{(8x^6 - 16x^5 - 80x^4 - 160x^3 - 64x - 64)/y^3}$$

for example, $(1,1)\in C$ maps to $(52,-376)\in E$. What I am seeking is a way to get back to $C$, i.e. the inverse of $f$.  How can it be computed?  The only related post I cound find was [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182044/151307) which is way above my head, and as far as I understand it's just about the existence of a rational inverse, not about its computation.

Comment: see comments by Tomita at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502662/when-is-c44bc3-4b4-an-integer-square

Comment: There is a different elliptic curve but also no transformation, neither forward no backwards. So how han that help?

Comment: Using that other curve $E:y^2=x^3+x-1$ , the coordinates will be smaller (divides $x$ by 4 and $y$ by 8), but the task of inverting $f$ doesn't get more obvious, IMO. @Will Jagy

Comment: Does `f.inverse()` not work?

Comment: No. It's a multivariate function.  Moreover, I doubt it is globally invertible so that the inverse only exists when restricted to $C$ and $E$.
@Viktor Vaughn

Comment: See MacLeod's answer [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591990/birational-equivalence-of-diophantine-equations-and-elliptic-curves/1592599#1592599]